# How to create admin menu to call a function (replacing cronjob)

Tags: adminhtml

I have created a custom module to sync product details. There is a cron job configured to run model "my_module/Cron::syncDetail". I would like to convert this to a manual job in admin menu.

The syncDetail function in Cron.php is executing

`Mage::getModel('My_Module_Model_Product')->syncDetails();`

i have managed to create the admin menu drop down, however i can't figure out what to put in the action of the menu.

my question is what is the correct action to directly call the model function?

Answer (score 4):

Another option you may be interested in, which allows you to keep the current cron job setup, as well as run it manually, is to install [AOE Scheduler](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html). It is a highly regarded extension for working with cron jobs and one of its abilities is to run jobs directly from Magento Admin.

Comment: "Enhancing" (or replacing...not sure which is more accurate, honestly...) the default Magento Scheduler with AOE_Scheduler ought to be a standard part of all builds, imho.  Curious to see how this compares in Magento 2

Comment: In case you have trouble [finding the “Run now” option in newer versions of the extension](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler/issues/203).

Answer (score 3):

You can not call the model function directly from the admin menu. You need to implement a controller which calls the model function. Your menu entry should target the controller action. For moe information please refer to: http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_controllers